# Scroll when div content is outside viewport

Tags: javascript, jquery, viewport, scrollto

I've got a simple piece of code like this

http://jsfiddle.net/QTa2c/

and all I want is, when user click on some of the last elements in list to show the content,

```
$('a.showMeThis').click(function() {
   $(this).next('.content').slideToggle('fast', function() {
       // there's go all the magic
   });
});
```

and it goes outside the viewport (partly or completely) - scroll of the height of div, so he can see all of the content.

I was looking a lot for some logic for this, playing around with position().top, window.innerHeight and more, but it never goes in the way I want…

Hope you guys will help me, take care and have a nice day!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With condition it looks like this: http://jsfiddle.net/QTa2c/1/

```
if ($(this).parent().offset().top + $(this).height() > window.innerHeight + $(window).scrollTop())
          {
              var a = $(this)
              $('html,body').animate({scrollTop: $(a).parent().offset().top})
          }
```

I think, this code is enough to understand the logic =)

UPD: note, that you should insert `return false;` into `.click` event to prevent jumping to `#` anchor.

Answer (score 4):

Use [.animate()](http://api.jquery.com/animate/) and [.offset()](http://api.jquery.com/offset/)

```
$('a.showMeThis').click(function () {
    var $this = $(this);
    $this.next('.content').slideToggle('fast', function () {
        $('html,body').animate({
            scrollTop: $this.offset().top
        }, 'slow');
    });
});
```

<kbd>[**Fiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/cse_tushar/G9k7j/)</kbd>

---

Updated after OP's comment

<kbd>[**Updated Fiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/cse_tushar/G9k7j/4/)</kbd>

```
$('a.showMeThis').click(function () {
    var $this = $(this);
    $this.next('.content').slideToggle('fast', function () {
        if ($this.position()) {
            if ($this.position().top + $this.height() > $(window).scrollTop() + (window.innerHeight || document.documentElement.clientHeight)) {
                $('html,body').animate({
                    scrollTop: $this.position().top - (window.innerHeight || document.documentElement.clientHeight) + $this.height() + 15 + $this.next('.content').height()
                }, 100);
            }
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Yeah, but I need a condition - when it goes outside the viewport, animate(scroll), not in all cases, only when .content goes outside the viewport.

Comment: For which case is `document.documentElement.clientHeight` there?

Comment: @morodeer for `IE<8` support

Comment: Still doesn't. You're trying to get height of `$this`, but should get height of `$this.next('.content')`